# Using Java config with Spring Security for annotation-based role checks and Basic HTTP Auth

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to accomplish annotation-based (using `@PreAuthorize`) permission checking on one of my controllers. I'm using Java config, and have a `SecurityConfig` class extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

I'm also using Basic HTTP Authentication to get to the methods that require authorization.

But - the problem is, I **don't** want the `SecurityConfig` determining which methods require authentication using an `antPattern()` or similar. That's what the annotations are for!

How can I configure my `SecurityConfig` class so that it properly uses HTTP Basic authentication and the configured `AuthenticationManager` for methods with `@PreAuthorize`, and allows anonymous access to controller methods that *do not* have any security annotations attached?

**When I try this (Attempt #1):**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("craig").password("craigpass").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

My unprotected methods fail with:

`Full authentication is required to access this resource`

And my protected (but properly-authenticating) tests fail with:

`Error: Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?`

**When I try this (Attempt #2):**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("craig").password("craigpass").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

My unprotected methods fail with a `302` status code, and redirect to `/login`, and my protected/authenticating methods fail with:

`Error: Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?`

**When I try this (Attempt #3):**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("craig").password("craigpass").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

My authenticating method works properly. (Woo hoo!) But, my unprotected method fails with `401` because my `HttpSecurity` has seemingly been configured to *only* allow access if you're authenticated - regardless of whether the controller method is annotated with `@PreAuthorize`.

**When I try this (Attempt #4):**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("craig").password("craigpass").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

My unprotected methods work properly (allow access), but my authenticating methods (whether they have the proper HTTP auth or not) fail with status code `403`:

`Error: Access Denied`

**My authenticating test method** that fails with `403` uses `MockMvc` and sends in a request using headers:

`{Content-Type=[application/json], Accept=[application/json], Authorization=[Basic Y3JhaWc6Y3JhaWdwYXNz]}`

Which I have decoded and verified, and a URL `/api/item` with method `POST`, which should target the corresponding method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/item", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public void postNewItem(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar the only difference is that i had some very customized authentication method. If the only thing you want is to check for user role you should use `@Secured` instead of `@PreAuthorize` on your controller methods e.g.

```
@Secured({"ROLE_SOMEROLE"})
public void doSomething(...) {
}
```

Where the role is set in `AuthenticationProvider` as a list of `SimpleGrantedAuthority` with `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.
Here is the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationProvider authProvider;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // Had some other calls for CORS ajax requests.
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/logout")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .csrf()
            .disable();
}

}
```

If your methods are annotated with `@Secured` and the current user does not have specified role the client will receive a `403` response else the request goes through. If you are trying to run unit testing you can use `@Profile('test')` on your beans and use `AuthenticationProvider` with hard coded data. Here a post on this type of approach:
https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/