# Spring Security Configuration Fails

Tags: spring, spring-security, configuration

I am having some issues with spring web security and my database. If I use

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BBSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> cfg = auth.jdbcAuthentication();
        cfg.dataSource(dataSource);
        cfg.usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT user_name, password, true FROM user_data WHERE user_name=?");
        cfg.passwordEncoder(new MyPasswordEncoder());
        cfg.authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT user_name, concat('ROLE_',role) FROM user_data WHERE user_name=?");
     }
}
```

The method is successfully called, but in the log I see this

`Using default security password: 81456c65-b6fc-43ee-be41-3137d02b122b`

and my database code is never used.

If, instead, I use (in the same class)

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
    JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> cfg = auth.jdbcAuthentication();
    ... same config code as above
 }
```

it works fine, but sometimes `configureGlobal` is called before `setDataSource` and I get an `IllegalStateException` because `dataSource` was not injected before it was used.

I would like to understand what else is needed to make the first method work.

Also is there any way to control the order of `@Autowired`. Adding `@DependsOn(DataSource)` to `configureGlobal` has no effect.

Comment: Try to put an `Autowired` on `configure` method. Also, Did you use `configureGlobal` and `configure` at the same time?

Comment: Putting Autowired on configure method would be the same as the second method, an injection of `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`, not an override of configure. configure is suggested in the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218354/difference-between-registerglobal-configure-configureglobal-configureglo

Comment: Autowired works except for the issue with order of injection, where sometimes `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` is injected before `dataSource`, but I would be interested in why configure appears to work, but the configured `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` is not subsequently used for authentication.

Comment: Appears to have been gremlins. Both methods work. I did, however, learn about multiple object injection from Ali. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use *Field Injection* instead of *Setter Injection*:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BBSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // Same stuff
    }
}
```

Or inject the `Datasource` directly to the `configureGlobal` method:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
    // same stuff
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! Did not know that I could inject two objects at once.
Also, appears that gremlins caused the override approach to fail. Rebuilt and that mechanism appears to be working as well.